# Same margin between div on different resolution css

Tags: css, reactjs

[image]

What I'm trying to do is same margin between div container on different resolution. I'm using vh as a margin unit between container but it's not responsive like 2vh is ok for 1000px width and greater resolution but it looks bigger between 600px to 999px width resolution . So I opted to use media query but I think this is not efficient is there other way to make the margin looks the same on different resolution without using media query?

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes vh doesn't work as expected. You could try to use percentages but you have to understand it is very hard to get it similar without media queries because of the different ratios in different screens. If you would like it to be a set amount of pixels you can use min-height and max-height in a margin container.